# Is there any chance to get back the date time when a Key was stored in Redis?

Tags: redis, counter

Well I guess the question is self explanatory itself.
I would like to know when a key has been stored or modified (i.e. last modification time) That would be a datetime or unixts. Definitely not the TTL.

This would be useful for implementing a counter and to check increments every once. And compare increment with duration.

maybe there's a better approach?

Or the only solution is to store an object with datetime & count attributes? Instead of a simple value?

Comment: Redis prides itself in efficiency. So I'm pretty sure it doesn't store unneeded metadata (such as creation / modification timestamps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can`t get that data because of redis do not store nothing else TTL. And yes, you can use some metadata solution to got this.

Something like (php sample):

```
function setKey($key, $value) {
    $redis->set($key, $value);
    $redis->hSetNx($key . 'meta', 'createdAt', time()); 
    $redis->hSet($key . 'meta', 'updatedAt', time());
}

function setKeyTtl($key, $ttl) {
    $redis->ttl($key, $ttl);
    $redis->hSet($key . 'meta', 'ttlSetAt', time());
    $redis->hSet($key . 'meta', 'ttl', $ttl);
    $redis->ttl($key . 'meta', $ttl + 3600);
}
```

Use HSET as meta data storage. use [hSetNx](http://redis.io/commands/hsetnx) for fields which should be set just once (for example `createdAt`). You shoukd thing about workaround with meta ttl - in my sample i`l use meta ttl as key ttl + 1 hour. Here is many different cases based on bussines logic you want.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I wasn't  thinking about TTL because my counter should never expire. Non need then to update the TTL.